# Concat many data with pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation, google-colaboratory

I have 12 dataframes, for 12 different months of the year. I want to concat them at one to make my life a lot easier. Although i can read all the csvs without any ram problem, i can't concat them. (I am using google colab). I have tried:

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.concat([read_csv(f) for f in names_list])
```

read_csv is a function that gets the csv name, preprocessing the dataframe and at the end return back a dataframe. When i am doing this i get: tcmalloc: large alloc.
I also tried another solution which i saw here, where it concats all the csvs into one and then read them but i also get an error.
Is there a way to "break" my concat into pieces so if a read 3 csvs and aply concat function, then free ram and continue doing this?
It is very strange that although i can have all the 12 dataframes stored at df1,df2... etc, i can't find a way to have all them stored at one df.
I think tha the problem is not that i ask more ram than i have, but that i am asking a lot of ram at once!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens if you use a generator expression instead of a list comprehension?

Comment: You mean just to change [ ] at  ( )
?

Comment: If you say "Although i can read all the csvs without any ram problem", do you mean you can read all 12 at once? So `df1, df2, df3` etc?

Comment: Nope, `pd.concat([read_csv(f) for f in names_list])` -> `pd.concat((read_csv(f) for f in names_list))`.

Comment: I mean that i can use a loop and store the 12 dataframes at a dict, with key the name of csv and value tha dataframe tha read_csv return

Comment: @AMC TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'generator'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid

Comment: @Engineer_auth1234 Oops, I must have forgotten the valid input types for `pandas.concat()`....

Comment: @Engineer_auth1234 How about a loop over `names_list`, and at each iteration you get a single new DataFrame which you concat with result/main DataFrame?

Comment: You mean something like